# SDL - android port - how to open image in apk file from c code?

Tags: android, sdl, apk

Can somebody give an example of opening asset file in apk, which is called from native code? SDL 1.3 have "Android_JNI_FileOpen()" function, but I can't understand how to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually what you need to do is to create SDL_RWops from file - on Android file is taken from apk. So simple.

Old code:

```
/* Load graphics */
image = IMG_Load("/sdcard/imagename.type");
```

New code:

```
/* Load graphics */
SDL_RWops *file = SDL_RWFromFile("imagename.type", "rb");
image = IMG_Load_RW(file, 1);
```

P.S. File must be in "assets" directory in apk.

Comment: If it's in "assets", why is the path "/sdcard/"?